# Use a C++ compiled code within a R Shiny app in shinyapp.io

Tags: c++, r, shiny

I have developed a ShinyApp that is built around a C++ program. In short, what the app does is :

- provides a nice interface to setup the parameters (in a text file) for the C++ app
- runs the C++ compiled code using the `system(...)` command
- displays the output of the C++ code using `ggplot2`

The C++ compiled code is stored into the `www` folder. Locally it works fine, but when I load the app to the shinyapp website (I have a free subscription), I got the following error:

`sh: 1: ./a.out: Permission denied`

with `a.out` being my compile c++ code. Any idea if

1. I am doing something wrong?
2. It is possible call a compiled c++ code within shinyapp.io?

Comment: The execute flag is set for your executable?

Comment: @SimonKraemer not sure what the execute flag is.... As I said in the question, it work locally, so it be no? Or is a Shiny property?

Comment: It should be possible. I run `.bat` files from shiny. Maybe try that workaround (call `a.out` from a bat)

Comment: @Mathias711I can try that. could you just elaborate on how to do it?

Comment: `shell('/path/to/batfile') within the Shiny environment. Within the .bat you can call the `a.out` by just stating `a.out`. I call another executable, but the idea is the same. I do not know why, but I end the bat file with `exit /b 0`.

Comment: @Wiliam Your error code shows me that you are executing on a linux or unix machine. Executables must have the executable flag set to be executable. Maybe it got lost when copying it up to the server?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions#Notation_of_traditional_Unix_permissions

Comment: @SimonKraemer Ok, I understand. Just not sure how to fix it... Is it an option I should to the g++ when I compile my executable? Sorry if that is a dummy question, I am starting in c++

Comment: @Wiliam If this causes your problem it won't be because of C++ but on how linux/unix systems work. If you can open a bash please cd into the directory where `a.out` is, run `ls -l` and check the flags with the wikipedia article I sent you. If the file is not executable for all please let me know in the comments what rights are set on the file.

Answer (score 1):

This is a super old question, but since I stumbled on it looking for an answer for my identical problem, I would share what worked for me.

I didn't try the .bat suggestion mentioned in the comments, because that seemed to be tied to Windows OS and Shiny uses Linux.

Instead, I used R's Sys.chmod() function. In your case, if you are calling system("a.out"), before that line, put Sys.chmod("a.out", mode="777"). Note that you may want to look more into what chmod does with regards to permissions. But the code would look like:

```
// ...
Sys.chmod("a.out", mode="777")
system("a.out")
// ... remaining code
```